# how to deploy shinyapp on client local server?

Tags: r, docker, shiny, deployment, shinydashboard

I have developed a shiny app for a client and he needs it to be deployed on his local server for confidentiality concerns. The client prepared for a Debian VM with some sufficient characteristics, but I am not sure how to deploy it without surprising errors. Is there any tutorial on how to do it that you can share please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free version of [Shiny Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/). You can install it in a VM and deploy your app there. Dean Attali has an excellent tutorial of how to [install Shiny Server in Digital Ocean](https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/) that you can use for installing it on a VM, the steps are almost the same.